# How to break out of a loop if it is contained in a function

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c

I am trying to figure out how to break out of a loop if it is being called from a function.  I have a similar post, [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31596/arduino-serial-response-is-slow-when-in-while-loop/31597#31597), that I've decided to do something with the Arduino onboard LED, to isolate it from the NeoPixels Library and it is giving me the same issue.  The answers I have received there have been helpful but something is still puzzling me.

Using serial from the Arduino to my PC, the below "Example 1" code, can break out of a local loop successfully (and immediately) when the Arduino received keyboard input with key "2".

```
//Example 1
int ledPIN = 13; // sets up onboard LED on Arduino located near PIN13
char rx_byte = 0; // variable to hold serial input from console;  
int count = 0; // placeholder for incrementing during debugging of loops

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode (ledPIN, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {    // is a character available?
    rx_byte = Serial.read();       // get the character

    // check if a number was received
    if ((rx_byte >= '0') && (rx_byte <= '9')) {
      switch(rx_byte) {
        case '1':
          Serial.println("You've entered: 1");
          for (int i; i <=5000; i++) {
            rx_byte = Serial.read(); // must read character again
            if (rx_byte == '2') {
              Serial.println("Quitting...");
              digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);  // turn LED pin 13 off
              break;
            }
            else {
              Serial.println(i);
              digitalWrite(ledPIN, HIGH); // turn LED pin 13 on
            }
          }
          digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);  // turn LED pin 13 off
          break;

      }
    } // end: if (Serial.available() > 0)
  }
}
```

From what I've been told, you shouldn't necessarily perform a "serial.read()" inside of a loop.  However, if I do not include that in the for loop, it does not allow for any further input.

Since "Example 1" works, I am now trying to accomplish the same principle, but, this time, when calling a function which contains its own independent loop of course.  I've spent countless hours trying to resolve this.

I was under the impression that I could use a while loop within "void loop()" and call in a function which also contains a loop, then be able to break it from the while loop.  When attempting this various ways, the for loop within the function seems to blink the LED 10+ times and totally ignores my keystroke "2" to break the loop and is now infinite.  I know I could just put the for loop up in "void loop()" and it would work to break out similar to Example 1, but I'm sure it can be broken from a function as well.  I will eventually have similar functions that will contain parameters.

How would I go about doing this the correct way?

Below is "Example 2" that I am trying to break from the function.  I'm assuming it's an issue with doing it from the while loop?

Again, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
//Example 2
int ledPIN = 13; // sets up onboard LED on Arduino located near PIN13
char rx_byte = 0; // variable to hold serial input from console;  
int count = 0; // placeholder for incrementing during debugging of loops

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode (ledPIN, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {    // is a character available?

    rx_byte = Serial.read();       // get the character
    boolean forceTerminate = false;

    // check if a number was received
    if ((rx_byte >= '0') && (rx_byte <= '9')) {

      switch(rx_byte) {
        case '1':
          Serial.println("You've entered: 1");
          while(forceTerminate == false) {
            rx_byte = Serial.read(); // must read character again
            if (rx_byte == '2') {
              Serial.println("Quitting...");
              digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);  // turn LED pin 13 off
              forceTerminate = true;
              break;
            }
            else {
              //count = count+1;
              //Serial.println(count);
              blinkPIN13(); // FUNCTION: blinkPIN13
            }
          }
          digitalWrite(ledPIN, LOW);  // turn LED pin 13 off
          break;

      } // end: switch(rx_byte)

    } 

  } // end: if (Serial.available() > 0)

}

/************************************************************************************
 * FUNCTION for blinking LED located on PIN 13 to the state of ON(1)/OFF(0)
 ************************************************************************************/
void blinkPIN13() {

  for (int i; i <=10; i++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPIN,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To tell a function-caller what to do when the function exits, have the function return a status value.  You can do this at multiple levels.  For example:

```
byte doOtherStuff(int howLong) {
  digitalWrite(ledPIN, HIGH);
  delay(howLong);
  if (doneDoing()) return false;  
  digitalWrite(ledPIN,LOW);
  delay(howLong);
  return !doneDoing();
}

void loop() {
  while(doMore) {
    doStuff();
    for (byte i=0; i<9 && doMore; ++i) {
      doMore = doOtherStuff(1234);
    }
    if (doMore) {
      doMoreOtherStuffInWhile();
    }
  }
}
```